# R Extracting inner node information and splits from ctree (partykit)

Tags: r, function, plot, party

Hi I'm currently trying to extract some of the inner node information stored in the constant partying object in R using ctree in partykit but I'm finding navigating the objects a bit difficult, I'm able to display the information on a plot but I'm not sure how to extract the information - I think it requires nodeapply or another function in the partykit?

```
library(partykit)
irisct <- ctree(Species ~ .,data = iris)
plot(irisct, inner_panel = node_barplot(irisct))
```

[Plot with inner node details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWwZc.png)

All the information is accessible by the functions to plot, but I'm after a text output similar to: 
[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm9dA.gif)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main trick (as previously pointed out by @G5W) is to take the `[id]` subset of the `party` object and then extract the data (by either `$data` or using the `data_party()` function) which contains the response. I would recommend to build a table with absolute frequencies first and then compute the relative and marginal frequencies from that. Using the `irisct` object the plain table can be obtained by

```
tab <- sapply(1:length(irisct), function(id) {
  y <- data_party(irisct[id])
  y <- y[["(response)"]]
  table(y)
})
tab
##            [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
## setosa       50   50    0    0    0    0    0
## versicolor   50    0   50   49   45    4    1
## virginica    50    0   50    5    1    4   45
```

Then we can add a little bit of formatting to a nice `table` object:

```
colnames(tab) <- 1:length(irisct)
tab <- as.table(tab)
names(dimnames(tab)) <- c("Species", "Node")
```

And then use `prop.table()` and `margin.table()` to compute the frequencies we are interested in. The `as.data.frame()` method transform from the `table` layout to a "long" `data.frame`:

```
as.data.frame(prop.table(tab, 1))
##       Species Node        Freq
## 1      setosa    1 0.500000000
## 2  versicolor    1 0.251256281
## 3   virginica    1 0.322580645
## 4      setosa    2 0.500000000
## 5  versicolor    2 0.000000000
## 6   virginica    2 0.000000000
## 7      setosa    3 0.000000000
## 8  versicolor    3 0.251256281
## 9   virginica    3 0.322580645
## 10     setosa    4 0.000000000
## 11 versicolor    4 0.246231156
## 12  virginica    4 0.032258065
## 13     setosa    5 0.000000000
## 14 versicolor    5 0.226130653
## 15  virginica    5 0.006451613
## 16     setosa    6 0.000000000
## 17 versicolor    6 0.020100503
## 18  virginica    6 0.025806452
## 19     setosa    7 0.000000000
## 20 versicolor    7 0.005025126
## 21  virginica    7 0.290322581

as.data.frame(margin.table(tab, 2))
##   Node Freq
## 1    1  150
## 2    2   50
## 3    3  100
## 4    4   54
## 5    5   46
## 6    6    8
## 7    7   46
```

And the split information can be obtained with the (still unexported) `.list.rules.party()` function. You just need to ask for *all* node IDs (the default is to use just the terminal node IDs):

```
partykit:::.list.rules.party(irisct, i = nodeids(irisct))
##                                                               1 
##                                                              "" 
##                                                               2 
##                                           "Petal.Length <= 1.9" 
##                                                               3 
##                                            "Petal.Length > 1.9" 
##                                                               4 
##                       "Petal.Length > 1.9 & Petal.Width <= 1.7" 
##                                                               5 
## "Petal.Length > 1.9 & Petal.Width <= 1.7 & Petal.Length <= 4.8" 
##                                                               6 
##  "Petal.Length > 1.9 & Petal.Width <= 1.7 & Petal.Length > 4.8" 
##                                                               7 
##                        "Petal.Length > 1.9 & Petal.Width > 1.7"
```

Comment: Thanks very much Achim! I was wondering how to get all the nodes listed with list.rules, I'll check out the data_party function also as I think it will come in handy too.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the information that you want is accessible without much work. 
I will show how to get the information, but leave you to format the 
information into a pretty table.

Notice that your tree structure `irisct` is just a list of each of the nodes.

```
length(irisct)
[1] 7
```

Each node has a field `data` that contains the points that have made it down
this far in the tree,  so you can get the number of observations at the node
by counting the rows.

```
dim(irisct[4]$data)
[1] 54  5
nrow(irisct[4]$data)
[1] 54
```

Or doing them all at once to get your table 2

```
NObs = sapply(1:7, function(n) { nrow(irisct[n]$data) })
NObs
[1] 150  50 100  54  46   8  46
```

The first column of the data at a node is the class (Species),
so you can get the count of each class and the probability of each class
at a node

```
table(irisct[4]$data[1])
setosa versicolor  virginica 
     0         49          5 
table(irisct[4]$data[1]) / NObs[4]
setosa versicolor  virginica 
0.00000000 0.90740741 0.09259259
```

The split information in your table 3 is a bit more awkward. Still, 
you can get a text version of what you need just by printing out the 
top level node

```
irisct[1]
Model formula:
Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
Fitted party:
[1] root
|   [2] Petal.Length <= 1.9: setosa (n = 50, err = 0.0%)
|   [3] Petal.Length > 1.9
|   |   [4] Petal.Width <= 1.7
|   |   |   [5] Petal.Length <= 4.8: versicolor (n = 46, err = 2.2%)
|   |   |   [6] Petal.Length > 4.8: versicolor (n = 8, err = 50.0%)
|   |   [7] Petal.Width > 1.7: virginica (n = 46, err = 2.2%)
Number of inner nodes:    3
Number of terminal nodes: 4
```

To save the output for parsing and display

```
TreeSplits = capture.output(print(irisct[1]))
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! how to reference a node in the tree with $data seems to be a lot of what I'm looking for