# R partykit calculate classification probabilities on sub stree

Tags: r, traversal, decision-tree, party

I have trained a partykit package ctree classification decision tree and I need to calculate classification probabilities for sub tree (not only for leaf nodes).
So for example if a sub tree consists of 3 leaf nodes with the following probabilities:
leaf 1 (120 observations) : 0.45
leaf 2 (160 observations) : 0.49
leaf 3 (190 observations) : 0.83

for this hypothetical sub tree the weighted average probability would be
120*0.42 + 160*0.49 + 190*0.83 / (120+160+190) = 0.507

and so on I need to traverse on the ctree object and calculate all weighted probabilities for each node recursively.

I have this code:

```
data(airquality)
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq,
                 controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
traverse <- function(treenode){
    if(treenode$terminal){
      bas=paste("Current node is terminal node with",treenode$nodeID,'prediction',treenode$prediction)
      print(bas)
      return(0)
    } else {
      bas=paste("Current node",treenode$nodeID,"Split var. ID:",treenode$psplit$variableName,"split value:",treenode$psplit$splitpoint,'prediction',treenode$prediction)
      print(bas)
    }
    traverse(treenode$left)
    traverse(treenode$right)
  }
```

which traverse on the tree does not work on partykit object.
On the other hand I have this code, which lists all porbabilities for leaf nodes only :

```
preds.ls <- list(predict(airct , type = "prob"))[1]
pred.probs.df <- unique(as.data.frame((preds.ls[[1]])))
```

Any suggestions to combine these 2 snippets to a code that will traverse on a PARTYKIT object and calculate this weighted average are appreciated

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what exactly want to do as the code as posted contains some errors. However, I think that this answer will help you do what you want (or ask a more precise question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968910/r-extracting-inner-node-information-and-splits-from-ctree-partykit/41976697#41976697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `partykit` but this simple function walks a `ctree` and extracts the probability for every internal and terminal node:

```
   library(party)

    set.seed(100)
    dt <- ctree(factor(mpg > 20)~., data = mtcars,
                control = ctree_control(minsplit=2, minbucket=1, mincriterion=0))

    traverse <- function(node) {
      if (node$terminal) {
        return(node$prediction[2])
      }
      return(c(node$prediction[2],
               traverse(node$left), traverse(node$right)))
    }
```

[image]

Calling the function produces the following vector of probabilities:

```
> traverse(dt@tree)
[1] 0.4375000 1.0000000 0.1428571 0.4285714 0.7500000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

The left most value is the population value verified by the following:

```
> mean(mtcars$mpg > 20)
[1] 0.4375
```

The rest of the values are going to be in order from left to right. You can see that the 1s and 0s line up where expected.

Comment: Does this implementation take under consideration the number of observations for each leaf/terminal node ?

Comment: Yes, the internal node probabilities are the probabilities of the entire subtree.

Comment: Note that this solution pertains to the old `party` implementation but does not work for the newer `partykit` implementation. The representation of the tree changed significantly.

Comment: @ Achim Zeileis - Do you have any reference to a partykit solution to calculate sub tree probability ?